# Making a For Loop Parallel

Tags: c#, parallel.for

Can I use Parallel Programming in this section of code?

I'm running a For loop  for 1000s times.
 The extensive work inside this loop is the line (which playing game until the end...):

```
**PocGraph.Player Winner = Expand(MCPlayout);**
```

If i will use a parallel programming here, the final result of the function **Evaluate**
could be affected ?

```
public float Evaluate(PocGraph Current, Move move)
{
    int Value = 0;
    // value of move
    for (int Plays = 0; Plays < NumberOfPlayouts; Plays++)
    {
        PocGraph MCPlayout = Current.cloneGraph();
        MCPlayout.makeMoveMC(move.Position, Current.CurrentPlayer);
        PocGraph.Player Winner = Expand(MCPlayout);

        if (Winner == Current.CurrentPlayer)
            Value++;                                        // win means +1
        else if (Winner ==  PocGraph.GetOponentPlayer(Current.CurrentPlayer))
            Value--;                                        // loss means -1
    }
    return (Value / (float)NumberOfPlayouts);                // project into [-1,1]

}

protected PocGraph.Player Expand(PocGraph Game)
{
    // maybe the next move
    int MoveId;
    // until the game ends play it
    while (Game.testVictory() == PocGraph.Player.NONE)
    {
        List<Move> ValidMoves = Game.getValidMoves();
        MoveId = Rnd.Next(0, ValidMoves.Count - 1);               
        Game.makeMoveMC(ValidMoves[MoveId].Position, Game.CurrentPlayer);
    }
    // return the winner
    return Game.testVictory();
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Pretty sure you need a lock on `Value`

Comment: You could make the vaiables in each thread [ThreadStatic]